# Android Bluetooth

Tags: android, bluetooth

I'm new in android and I'm going to work with Bluetooth.
I have the code below but the problem is that it not display list of devices when I run the application in my phone. Other buttons turn on, turn off and get visible works without problem.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private Button On,Off,Visible,list;
   private BluetoothAdapter BA;
   private Set<BluetoothDevice>pairedDevices;
   private ListView lv;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

      On = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
      Off = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);
      Visible = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button3);
      list = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button4);

      lv = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1);

      BA = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
}


 //Button turn on
 public void on(View view){
      if (!BA.isEnabled()) {
         Intent turnOn = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
         startActivityForResult(turnOn, 0);
         Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Turned on" 
         ,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
      }
      else{
         Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Already on",
         Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
         }
   }

       //Button list devices
   public void list(View view){
      pairedDevices = BA.getBondedDevices();

      ArrayList list = new ArrayList();
      for(BluetoothDevice bt : pairedDevices)
         list.add(bt.getName());

      Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Showing Paired Devices",
      Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
      final ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter
      (this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, list);
      lv.setAdapter(adapter);

   }

       //Button turn off
   public void off(View view){
      BA.disable();
      Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Turned off" ,
      Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
   }

       //Button get visible
   public void visible(View view){
      Intent getVisible = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.
      ACTION_REQUEST_DISCOVERABLE);
      startActivityForResult(getVisible, 0);

   }

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Do you have permissions in your manifest file?

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN"/>
```

Comment: @nasroazro So, try to look into logcat. It's quiet hard to say what's wrong with your project without errors or logs.

Comment: the bluetooth don't work in the emulator so why I look into logcat. I tested it in my android phone (Galaxy SII)

Comment: @heri.wijoyo I tried to add the code at the end of 'onCreate' method but nothing list devices does not appear !

Comment: How to implement the 'onActivityResult' method in my example and what is the code inside ?

Answer (score 0):

why don't you implement the 'onActivityResult' method? if your code above was refer to any tutorial, please double check it.
i think that you missed to put 'onActivityResult' method.

EDIT:

try to add this code at the end of 'onCreate' method:

```
@Override
onCreate(...){
   ...

   ...
   list.setOnClickListener( new OnClickListener(){

       @Override
       public void onClick(View view){
           list();
       }

   });

}
```

i think you missed to call each method when the button is clicked.

Comment: My code refer to this tutorial [http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_bluetooth.htm] and I not found the method 'onActivityResult'here